# facebook SDK roles management

Tags: asp.net, facebook

is there a way to get the list of currently listed developers on a face book connect application i want to use this to validate if a user is authorized to sublmit new contenet and create events through the connect website or do i need to couple this with a forms authorization account to handle permissions

or is there a better way over all to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a user is a developer of some specific app you can run such FQL:

```
select application_id from developer where developer_id=me() and application_id=<APP_ID>
```

To check if a user granted your app some specific permission you can use this FQL (not sure if this would be helpful in your case though):

```
select uid from permissions where uid=me() and <PERMISSION_NAME>=1
```

where `<PERMISSION_NAME>` is one of [these](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions).

Comment: why use FQL? can he not do this with the Graph/JS/REST APIs?

Comment: @RPM1984 why not? FQL can be executed in Graph, JS, old REST APIs.

Comment: ok, but i thought it might be easier to invoke a regular API method, rather than writing the actual query. (assuming there is a method for this)

Comment: @RPM1984 There probably some method in old rest api for this, but I think using rest would be step in wrong direction as it is about to get deprecated (even though there still no 100% functionality  replacement).

Comment: tell me about it. :) I started creating a FB Connect app using the Graph API, then realised the wall posts don't support action links, so i had to revert to the JS api, haha. It still hasn't been fixed (bug has been open/voted for months).